# PHP не могу подключиться к БД

Tags: php, mysql

Выдает ошибку:
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\cosmopolitan\www\includes\nav.php on line 10`

Содержимое nav.php

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>

<?php

$mq ="select * from category";

$query = mysql_query($mq);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))         <-10 строка
{
    $catid = $row['cat_id'];
    $cattitle = $row['cat_title'];
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat=$catid'>$cattitle</a></li>";
}
?>
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Модуль mysql был удалён в PHP 7, лучше изучите mysqli или PDO

Comment: Скорее всего запрос ничего не выдал. `$query` у Вас равен `false`. Проверьте подключение к БД может там у Вас ошибка. А вообще, как писали выше, смотрите в сторону PDO, чтобы избежать дальнейших проблем с обновлением сервера.

Comment: Подключение есть, что делать с этим $query....это типа таблица вызываемая пустая....не понимаю....